# How to select rows above a certain condition grouping by a different column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
A   B   C
1   3   2
1   7   7
1   7   7
1   5   4
2   2   1
2   8   8
2   4   5
3   5   3
3   1   9
3   4   4
```

What I am trying to do is for each group of the same values in column A to find the last row with the value in column B equal to the value in C and then return rows before the LAST row where B = C, including the row itself. So expected outcome would be:

```
A   B   C
1   3   2
1   7   7
1   7   7
2   2   1
2   8   8
3   5   3
3   1   9
3   4   4
```

I have tried the code below but it returns rows before the first row where B = C, not before the last one.

```
mask = df['B'] == df['C']
df.loc[mask[::-1].groupby(df['A']).cummax()]
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df.index`?

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.index` as requested above? This would allow to confirm the source of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me working your solution correct, here is alternative with create helper column:

```
mask = df['B'] == df['C']
df = df[df.assign(m=mask).iloc[::-1].groupby('A')['m'].cummax()]
#or
#df = df[df.assign(m=mask).iloc[::-1].groupby('A')['m'].cummax().iloc[::-1]]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  3  2
1  1  7  7
2  1  7  7
4  2  2  1
5  2  8  8
7  3  5  3
8  3  1  9
9  3  4  4
```

Another idea is create default index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#OP solution
mask = df['B'] == df['C']
df.loc[mask[::-1].groupby(df['A']).cummax()]
```

EDIT: If need all rows before first same `B` with `C` columns use:

```
#sample data
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   1  3  2
1   1  7  7
2   1  7  7
3   1  5  4
4   1  7  7
5   1  2  2
6   2  2  1
7   2  8  8
8   2  4  5
9   3  5  3
10  3  1  9
11  3  4  4
12  4  7  7
13  4  7  7
14  4  7  5
15  5  4  4
16  5  4  4
17  5  1  1
18  5  1  1
19  6  8  4
```

---

```
#compare columns
m = df['B'] == df['C']
#create groups by consecutive B, C columns
df1 = df.assign(g = df[['B','C']].ne(df[['B','C']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum())
print (df1)
    A  B  C   g
0   1  3  2   1
1   1  7  7   2
2   1  7  7   2
3   1  5  4   3
4   1  7  7   4
5   1  2  2   5
6   2  2  1   6
7   2  8  8   7
8   2  4  5   8
9   3  5  3   9
10  3  1  9  10
11  3  4  4  11
12  4  7  7  12
13  4  7  7  12
14  4  7  5  13
15  5  4  4  14
16  5  4  4  14
17  5  1  1  15
18  5  1  1  15
19  6  8  4  16
```

---

```
#filter only matched B, C and aggregate min
s = df1[m].groupby('A')['g'].min()

#compare mapped A groups and filter if less or equal values
df2 = df[df1['g'].le(df['A'].map(s))]
print (df2)
    A  B  C
0   1  3  2
1   1  7  7
2   1  7  7
6   2  2  1
7   2  8  8
9   3  5  3
10  3  1  9
11  3  4  4
12  4  7  7
13  4  7  7
15  5  4  4
16  5  4  4
```

---

```
#if need only first row with same B, C chain duplicated
df3 = df[df1['g'].le(df['A'].map(s)) & ~df1['g'].duplicated()]
print (df3)
    A  B  C
0   1  3  2
1   1  7  7
6   2  2  1
7   2  8  8
9   3  5  3
10  3  1  9
11  3  4  4
12  4  7  7
15  5  4  4
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first solution works perfectly fine. How would it change if I want to return all the rows before the first, not the last one (in case of duplicates)?

Comment: @Andrei - Answer was edited with 2 solutions for `df2, df3`

Answer (score 2):

Using a reversed [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) is working as expected:

```
m = df['B'].eq(df['C'])
out = df[m[::-1].groupby(df['A']).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  2
1  1  7  7
2  1  7  7
4  2  2  1
5  2  8  8
7  3  5  3
8  3  1  9
9  3  4  4
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'B': [3, 7, 7, 5, 2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4],
                   'C': [2, 7, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 3, 9, 4]})
```

An error might come from an index with duplicated values, in which case you can bypass index alignment using the underlying numpy array and manually reverse the output:

```
grouper = df.loc[::-1, 'A'].values
out = df.loc[m[::-1].groupby(grouper).cummax()[::-1]]
```

Alternative input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'B': [3, 7, 7, 5, 2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4],
                   'C': [2, 7, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 3, 9, 4]},
                 index=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                 )
```

##### selecting all the rows before (and including) the first equality

```
tmp = df.assign(m=df['B'].ne(df['C']))
# rows before the first equality
m1 = tmp.groupby('A')['m'].cummin()
# first equality
m2 = ~tmp.duplicated(['A', 'm'])

out = df[m1|m2]
```

*NB. if you don't want to include the first equality, just use `out = df[m1]`.*

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  2
1  1  7  7
4  2  2  1
5  2  8  8
7  3  5  3
8  3  1  9
9  3  4  4
```

Comment: @Andrei I updated my answer for the rows before the first equality (do you want to include the first equality as well?)